# Inequality on an integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Suppose $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function and $(X,F,m)$ a measure space.  For all $C\in F$ with $m(C)>0$ $$\left| \frac{1}{m(C)}\int_C f dm\right|\le L$$ where $L>0$.  Need to show $|f|\le L$.  On a related question I know if $\int g dm < \infty$ then $g < \infty$ but is it true that if $\int g dm < L$ then $g<L$.  If the latter were true we would have $|\int_C fdm|\le m(C)L=\int_C Ldm$ which implies $|f|1_C \le L1_C$ or is this just complete garbage.

Comment: You could at most shows that $|f| \le L$ almost everywhere. To show this, you can assume the contrary..

Comment: @JohnMa So if $|f|>L$ then $\int| f| dm > \int Ldm \ge \int_C Ldm \ge |\int_C fdm|$ I dont see how this is untrue.

Comment: What's your $C$?

Comment: It is from $C \in F$

Comment: That's arbitrarily any $C\in F$?

Comment: @JohnMa but it is true that $|\int f dm| \le \int |f| dm$

Comment: Note that the negation of "$|f| \le L$ almost everywhere" is not $|f|>L$.

Comment: @JohnMa so the negation of $-L \le f \le L$ is $f >L$ or $f<-L$

Comment: It's not negating $|f| \le L$, it's "$|f| \le L$ almost everywhere".

Comment: @JohnMa so there exists a set $C\in F$ ie $m(C)>0$ st. $f>L$

Comment: You are right, there are some tricks in between, please see the answer. The tricks from $C$ to $C_n$ is common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the contrary, the set $\{|f| >L\}$ has positive measure. Write

$$\{ |f| > L \} = \{ f> L\} \cup \{ f< -L\}$$

then one of them has positive measure. Assume that $\{ f> L\}$ has positive measure (If not, consider $-f$ then).

As

$$\{ f > L\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ f\ge L + \frac 1n \right\},$$

there is a natural integer $n$ so that

$$C_n =  \left\{ f\ge L + \frac 1n \right\}$$

has positive measure (Why?). Then

$$\int_{C_n} f dm \ge \int_{C_n}\left( L + \frac 1n \right)dx = m(C_n)\left(L+\frac 1n \right)$$

which imply

$$\left| \frac{1}{m(C_n)}\int_{C_n} f dm\right|\ge L+\frac 1n >L$$

and this is a contradiction to the assumption. Thus $|f| \le L$ almost everywhere.